# Is it possible to register as a developer for Amazon SP-API without having a seller account?

Tags: amazon-mws

I plan to develop an app for Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API). The general idea of the app is that it will be the app, that different sellers can use to help them manage their stock on Amazon. I myself am not a seller on Amazon, and I don't work for a particular seller. The app, once ready, should be available to multiple sellers who are interested in using it.

Unfortunately, from what I found in `SP-API` documentation [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/) and [here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#registering-as-a-developer) it seems it's impossible to register as a developer, without being a seller yourself or having an existing seller that can register you as a developer. Is this correct? If yes, is there any way to overcome this issue? It seems a bit ridiculous that Amazon doesn't provide an easy way for third party developers to develop and test their apps on Amazon.

Comment: Ran into this hurdle. They also require your passport number to register an account to sell now, which I didn't fancy giving my personal information for a work related project. It resulted in us simply not supporting Amazon for the system we created. Amazon are the most backwards.

Answer (score 2):

They would require a Seller Central account to be set up for public applications to allow you to register as a developer. The main account would be used to access the developer registration form and can be used to set up developer access. This would also allow support cases to be raised. Be aware that they will charge a monthly fee. Recent updates to documentation appears to suggest this will only affect Public application developers.